# How to find Newest Employee Salary using Linq in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

I got this challenging question online while solving c# problems, to find this using SQL is easy but using LINQ seems difficult for me.
This is the data in the input.txt file.

```
22, Rajan Anand, Engineering, 1600000
23, Swati Patil, Testing, 800000
27, Vijay Chawda, Engineering, 800000
29, Basant Mahapatra, Engineering, 600000
32, Ajay Patel, Testing, 350000
34, Swaraj Birla, Testing, 350000
```

Output is: 
Engineering:600000
Testing: 350000

Please do change in processData function only. Help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

/* Don't change anything here.
 * Do not add any other imports. You need to write
 * this program using only these libraries 
 */

namespace ProgramNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {

        /* DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING ABOVE THIS LINE */

        public static Dictionary<String, int> processData(
                                        IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            /* 
             * Do not make any changes outside this method.
             *
             * Modify this method to process `array` as indicated
             * in the question. At the end, return the size of the
             * array. 
             *
             * Do not print anything in this method
             *
             * Submit this entire program (not just this function)
             * as your answer
             */
            Dictionary<String, int> retVal = new Dictionary<String, int>();
            return retVal;
        }

        /* DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW THIS LINE */

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<String, int> retVal = processData(
                                      File.ReadAllLines("input.txt"));
                File.WriteAllLines("output.txt",
                    retVal.Select(x => x.Key + ": " + x.Value).ToArray());
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: By "newest", do you mean "lowest"?

Comment: @canton7 I think it means employee with the highest id.  So for Engineering it was Basant Mahapatra with id 29 and for Testing it was Swaraj Birla with id 34.

Comment: Did you try anything?  What exact problems did you run into?

Comment: @juharr It might do - both fit the example data

Comment: @juharr He states that the output is *"Engineering:600000 Testing: 350000"*, so it appears that the result should be the industry as the key and the lowest salary as the value.

Comment: @RufusL It says the newest employee and the desired values belong to the employees in those positions with the highest ids which presumably means they are the newest employee.  Nothing says anything about lowest salary, I think that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return lines
  .Select(l=>l.Split(','))
  .GroupBy(i=>i[2])
  .ToDictionary(
    k=>k.Key, 
    v=>int.Parse(v.OrderByDescending(z=>int.Parse(z[0])).First()[3]));
```

Or more readable:

```
return lines
  .Select(l=>l.Split(','))
  .Select(z=>new {Id=int.Parse(z[0]), Name=z[1], Department=z[2], Salary=int.Parse(z[3])})
  .GroupBy(e=>e.Department)
  .ToDictionary(k=>k.Key,v=>v.OrderByDescending(z=>z.Id).First().Salary);
```

Comment: The keys that get returned will be prefixed by a space because the Split does not automatically do trimming.  Feel free to either trim the Key at the end, in the groupby, or in the anonymous object projection stages as you see fit.

Comment: Perfect and optimized answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code in processData function, you will get your output:

```cs
Dictionary<String, int> retVal = new Dictionary<String, int>();

Dictionary<int, string> empWithDepart = lines.Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0]), x => Convert.ToString(x[2]));
Dictionary<int, int> empWithSalary = lines.Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToDictionary(x => Convert.ToInt32(x[0]), x => Convert.ToInt32(x[3]));
var departWithHighestEmpID = empWithDepart.OrderByDescending(x => x.Key).GroupBy(x => x.Value)
                               .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.FirstOrDefault().Key).ToList();
departWithHighestEmpID.Sort((pair1, pair2) => pair1.Key.CompareTo(pair2.Key));
foreach (var item in departWithHighestEmpID)
{
    retVal.Add(item.Key, empWithSalary[item.Value]);
}

return retVal;
```